# Tengo una duda de como hacer mi html responsivo con boostrap5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

Actualmente estoy haciendo un solitario y en mi html uso div y ul, ya agregue los links de boostrap y las clases a los div y a los ul que están dentro del div, pero por alguna razón no se vuelve responsive, en cambio se desorganiza todo y se ponen todas las columnas desordenadas. Si pueden ayudarme diciéndome que debería cambiar se los agradecería

```html
<body>
  <div id="tablero" class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="contenedorColumnas list-group  list-group-horizontal">
        <li class="contenedorCartas1 list-group-item">
          <ul id="columna1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contenedorCartas2 list-group-item">
          <ul id="columna2" class="columDisplay list-group  list-group-horizontal" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contenedorCartas3 list-group-item">
          <ul id="columna3" class="columDisplay list-group  list-group-horizontal" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contenedorCartas4 list-group-item">
          <ul id="columna4" class="columDisplay list-group   list-group-horizontal" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contenedorCartas5 list-group-item">
          <ul id="columna5" class="columDisplay list-group  list-group-horizontal" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contenedorCartas6 list-group-item">
          <ul id="columna6" class="columDisplay list-group" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contenedorCartas7 list-group-item">
          <ul id="columna7" class="columDisplay list-group  list-group-horizontal" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>


      <div id="mazos" class="col-sm">
        <div id="mazo_Entrada"></div>
        <div id="almacen"></div>
        <div id="almacen2"></div>
        <div id="almacen3"></div>
        <div id="almacen4"></div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="js/solitario.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ Te recomiendo que mires este enlace e investigues un poco sobre grid, ya que es lo que principalemente se utiliza para hacer lo que buscas

Comment: sube foto de como  se desordena, editando la pregunta